# Downloading with wget using referer + cookie

Tags: wget

I'm trying to download a file from a website that requires login.
This command retrieves the **cookie.txt** and the downloaded html shows I'm logged in (ok):

*(I broke the command in lines for readability)*

```
wget 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" 
--keep-session-cookies
--save-cookies cookies.txt
--post-data "login_username=MyUserName&login_password=*******" 
--header="Host: somewebsite.com"
--header="Referer: http://somewebsite.com/files/download.php?i=2157716" 
http://somewebsite.com/login.php
```

Here I get cookies.txt. (all ok).
And after that: *(trying to download)*

```
wget 
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0" 
--load-cookies cookies.txt
--header="Host: somewebsite.com"
--header="Referer: http://somewebsite.com/files/download.php?i=2157716" 
--header="Connection: keep-alive" --header="Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5"
--header="Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
http://somewebsite.com/files/dl.php?t=2157716
```

But instead of downloading the file it returns an HTML saying that **the file can only be downloaded from the website.**

Here is the POST data from Firefox right before the download starts:

[image: post data from actual Firefox download]

What is missing?

Comment: Could be that the url you think is the download isn't. For example, `wget` doesn't handle javascript redirects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. The HTML has a hidden form that sends the request via POST. I just had to add `--post-data "login_username=****&login_password=****"`. The server only starts the download if it is POST request.